# Send SMS from iPhone Programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, sms

How can I send a SMS from an iPhone programmatically?

Yesterday, I found an example code and coded it but the code gave me a SMS dialog (internal SMS dialog).

I just want to send a SMS programmatically without the internal SMS dialog.

Is there any example code?

Comment: I hope not. Messaging is charged by providers, I'd hate to see a huge bill after your app has secretly sent 1M messages...

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, what you describe is completely impossible without a jailbroken device.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  All but the last sentence of your "answer" should have been a comment.

Comment: @paprika I'm a little late, but I finally fixed it :P